# input[time] Not Accepting Value From Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem getting my data formatted properly so that angularjs will populate the data  an input field with type "time".  Can you help me figure out what I am missing?

HTML:

```
<input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="stuff.starttime"
   placeholder="HH:mm:ss" min="00:00:00" max="17:00:00" >
```

Controller:

```
$scope.stuff = {
    originlevel2: "",
    destinationlevel2: "",
    destination2: "",
    origin2: "",
    starttime: "",
    endtime: ""
}
var starttime = jsonArray2[0]["starttime"];
$scope.stuff.starttime = new Date(starttime);
```

Comment: What is the value of `jsonArray2[0]["starttime"]`

Comment: The value is:  01:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of `jsonArray2[0]["starttime"]` is `01:00:00`.

Thus, `new Date(jsonArray2[0]["starttime"])` is invalid date.

You can instead the following :

```
var d=new Date();
starttime='01:00:00' // jsonArray2[0]["starttime"]
starttime=starttime.split(':').map((e)=>parseInt(e))
d.setHours(starttime[0]);
d.setMinutes(starttime[1]);
d.setSeconds(starttime[2]);

// Then
$scope.stuff.starttime= d;
```

After, that try with Chrome or safari .

---

## [Note](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_time):

> Note: type="time" is not supported in Firefox, or Internet Explorer 10
>   and earlier versions.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to get the same data that using, "starttime=starttime.split(':').map((e)=>parseInt(e))"?  Ionic is giving me the white screen of death in my app and here is the error " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>, http://192.168.135.1:8100/js/controllers.js"

Comment: a.map(function(e) { return parseInt(e, 10)}) Making this change took care of my issue with ionic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.stuff = {
    starttime: new Date(); // initialize as a date instead of a string
}
```

Basically your initialized your variable as a string. When you attempted to format that string as a date it caused it to fail. If you're expecting a date then set it to a new date.

Comment: This appears to have helped.  It's now populating the "time" input, but it's defaulting to the current time.  I can't seem to figure out how to convert my variable value of "01:00:00" and populate my input with that value.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.